# Angular, broadcast not working

Tags: angularjs

my aim is to send some data from an angular controller to another.

Here is the controller who has to send the datas :

```
myApp.controller('MapCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', function ($scope, $http) {
    $scope.loadData = function () {
        $http.get('/map/GetListDB').success(function (data, status, headers, config) {

            //Logic here is working fine, it creates a table named "ExcelCols" which is a table of strings

            $scope.$broadcast("SET_EXCEL_TITLES", $scope.ExcelCols);
        })
    }

}]);
```

Here is the second controller

```
myApp.controller('ExcelViewCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', function($scope, $http) {
    $scope.$on("SET_EXCEL_TITLES", function (event, excelCols) {

        //this event is never fired

        $scope.ExcelCols = excelCols;
    });
}]);
```

My view is designed that way :

```
 <body ng-app="myApp">
    <div ng-controller="MapCtrl">
         //everything OK here
    </div>

    <div ng-controller="ExcelViewCtrl">
      <table>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th ng-repeat="col in ExcelCols">{{col}}</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
       </table>          
    </div>

 </body>
```

Comment: How are the controllers instantiated? Are `ExcelViewCtrl` and its scope children of `MapCtrl`? See the difference between `$broadcast` and `$emit`.

Comment: Maybe I misunderstood that point. I think that $emit is used to send a message to the parent, and broadcast used to send something to every controller

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Depending upon how the controllers are structured w.r.t to `$broadcast` message would be routed.

As per [documentation](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.$rootScope.Scope)

> Dispatches an event name downwards to all child scopes (and their
>   children) notifying the registered ng.$rootScope.Scope#$on listeners.

This means the controller that is sending the broadcast should be defined on the parent html of the child controller html.

Based on your html structure, use `$rootScope.$broadcast`. Inject the `$rootScope` into the `MapCtrl` and call `$broadcast` method on it.

Answer (score 7):

I think you need to use `$rootScope` instead for `$scope.$broadcast`. See good example in [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/simpulton/huKHQ/)

Answer (score 3):

Below are the examples for AngularJS – Communicating Between Controllers:

Example with communication using shared service.

http://jsfiddle.net/simpulton/XqDxG/

```
"ControllerZero" Broadcast to "ControllerOne" and "ControllerTwo"
```

and Video Tutorial

http://onehungrymind.com/angularjs-communicating-between-controllers/

Comment: Thanks for the inspiration. I created a notification service that now handles all notification across the app. Keeps code very clean ... Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to use $rootScope to list to event and local $scope to emit it. I have created this plnkr to test it http://plnkr.co/edit/LJECQZ?p=info

```js
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('Ctl1', function($scope, $rootScope) {
  $scope.name = 'World';
  $rootScope.$on('changeValueInCtl1', function(event, value) {
    $scope.name = 'New Value from Ctl2 is: ' + value;
  });
});

app.controller('Ctl2', function($scope) {
  $scope.changeValue = function() {
    $scope.$emit('changeValueInCtl1', 'Control 2 value');
  }
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="plunker">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title>AngularJS Plunker</title>
  <script>
    document.write('<base href="' + document.location + '" />');
  </script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
  <script data-require="angular.js@1.5.x" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.11/angular.min.js" data-semver="1.5.11"></script>
  <script src="app.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div ng-controller="Ctl1">
    <p>Hello {{name}}!</p>
  </div>


  <div ng-controller="Ctl2">
    <button ng-click="changeValue()">Change Value</button>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

The only downside is the $rootScope will be listening and one has to explicitly call $destroy to it.